# PHP Function inside an HTML table

Tags: php, html, wordpress, taxonomy

I'm really new to PHP, and I am looking for a way to insert a function inside an HTML table.

I've worked on custom taxonomies on a WordPress site, and I would like to call a function inside a table which would display a series of information.

The function I have on the site at the moment is the following:

```
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'title', 'Title: ', ', ', ' ' ); ?>
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'subtitle', 'Subtitle: ', ', ', ' ' ); ?>
<?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'publisher', 'Publisher: ', ', ', ' ' ); ?>
```

I've tried doing the following:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>Title</td>
    <td><?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'title', 'Title: ', ', ', ' ' ); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Subtitle</td>
    <td><?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'subtitle', 'Subtitle: ', ', ', ' ' ); ?></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Publisher</td>
    <td><?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'publisher', 'Publisher: ', ', ', ' ' ); ?></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

But unfortunately it did not work.

Can anyone more expert than me tell me where I'm doing wrong?

Thank you in advance.

The complete code is the following:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying single posts
 *
 * @package Tortuga
 */

?>

<article id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>>

    <header class="entry-header">

        <?php the_title( '<h1 class="entry-title">', '</h1>' ); ?>

        <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'title', 'Title: ', ', ', ' ' ); ?>
        <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'subtitle', 'Subtitle: ', ', ', ' ' ); ?>
        <?php the_terms( $post->ID, 'publisher', 'Publisher: ', ', ', ' ' ); ?>

    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <div class="entry-content clearfix">


        <?php the_content(); ?>

        <?php wp_link_pages( array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'tortuga' ),
            'after'  => '</div>',
        ) ); ?>

    </div><!-- .entry-content -->

    <footer class="entry-footer">

        <?php tortuga_entry_tags(); ?>
        <?php tortuga_post_navigation(); ?>

    </footer><!-- .entry-footer -->

</article>
```

The function I'm trying to insert inside the TD table is [the_terms](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/)

Comment: What isn't working? Where's the definition for `the_terms`?

Comment: It took it from here: [link](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/the_terms/)

Comment: Please post the code in your question as text. Each question should be a complete whole that doesn't rely on links to external sites.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know external links were not allowed. I added the complete code to the question.

Comment: Thanks. External links are heavily frowned upon because, what happens if the other site goes down or the link goes dead? Your question is then incomplete and less useful for future readers. If all the necessary information is embedded in the question, it will always be a complete whole.

Comment: I will pay more attention in the future. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.

Comment: @Carcigenicate I think in this case it might be acceptable as the function he's calling is part of a library provided by WP.  It's not reasonable to post the entire library being used.

Comment: @akousmata Maybe, although there's no guarantee the other site will remain forever. Given this question is all about the behavior of `the_terms` though, even an incomplete snippet of the code would have been better than nothing, just to get a feel for what it does. Maybe I'll ask on meta at what point external links to code are appropriate.

Comment: @kelqaisi your question is still somewhat vague.  Does your call to `the_terms` work when it isn't inside a table?  Start with getting it to work first, then add it to a table.  Also, it's a library from WordPress, there's several examples out there I found just by googling `wordpress the_terms examples`.  Check out the SE site dedicated to wordpress as well, they can probably help you better http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @akousmata The function is working (I'm using the first code in my question); what I'm unable to do is to insert the data inside a table's cells (TD tag).